# Configuring Eclipse (on windows) for Hadoop environment(on vm having SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 )

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, hadoop

I had Install Hadoop in pseudo-distributed mode on a VMware having SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11. I am able to run the hello world examples like word count. Also I used WinSCP to connect to that VM and uploaded several XML files into hadoop cluster.

My question is now how can I configure my eclipse which I am having on my local machine that is windows 7 to connect that VM and write some java code to play with data I had dumped in the cluster. I did some work and able to get Map/Reduce perspective in the eclipse but not able to figure out how to connect hadoop on VM from my local machine, write my java code (mapper,reducer classes) to play with data and save the result back in cluster.

If someone can help me with this that will be great. Thanks in advance.

Let me know if more information is needed.

I am using hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u5 and eclipse europa 3.3.1

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling with this as well at the moment. Maybe you will find these links helpful:

- http://www.bigdatafarm.com/?p=4
- http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module3.html

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for suggesting links. I had already tried yahoo one and your other link seems to be broken. As if now I am just exporting jar files from my local machine on to the cluster and than doing development work. It seems that most of the people are doing the same thing.